# SVG Animate polilines transition

Tags: svg, svg-animate

Could anyone post an example of how to animate svg polyline or path?

I want to animate a transition from blue to gray lines. Ideally I'm looking for a solution which works out of whatever gray line is without knowing the number of coordinates of its' points.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 200px; width: 500px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">

        <svg height="200" width="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <polyline points="20,20 40,25 60,40 80,120 120,140 200,180"
                      style="fill: none; stroke: gray; stroke-width: 3" />

            <polyline points="20,20 40,20 60,20 80,20 120,20 200,20"
                      style="fill: none; stroke: blue; stroke-width: 3" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can animate a polyline using SMIL via the animate tag. If you need IE support then you'd have to use something like [fakeSmile](http://leunen.me/fakesmile/).

You will need to keep the number of points the same i.e. if you have a 10 point polygon you'll have to transition it to a 10 point polygon to get a smooth transition otherwise it will do step change transitions. You can always double up points on one of the polygon to make them have the same number of points.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 200px; width: 500px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">

        <svg height="200" width="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <polyline points="20,20 40,20 60,20 80,20 120,20 200,20"
                      style="fill: none; stroke: blue; stroke-width: 3">
                <animate dur="5s" fill="freeze" attributeName="points"
                         to="20,20 40,25 60,40 80,120 120,140 200,180"/>
                <animate dur="5s" fill="freeze" attributeName="stroke"
                         to="gray"/>
            </polyline>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```